# Momentum equation of a beam hitting a stationary target to create antiprotons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, collision

I'm struggling with the solution of a physics exercise which is to calculate the minimum energy needed to create antiprotons when a proton beam scatters on a stationary proton target:

$$p + p \rightarrow p + p + p + \bar p$$

The solution states that

$$(p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu) \equiv ({p_1^\mu}' + {p_2^\mu}' + {p_3^\mu}' + {\bar p_4^\mu}')$$

which makes sense to me but then it states

$$(E_1 + E_2)^2 - \vec p_1^2 = (4m_p)^2$$

So I think the first equation was squared and reformed with $ \pmb p^2 = E^2 - \vec p^2 = m^2$ but I don't get how it makes sense, because if
$({p_1^\mu}' + {p_2^\mu}' + {p_3^\mu}' + {\bar p_4^\mu}')^2 = (4m_p)^2$ why isn't it $(p_1^\mu + p_2^\mu)^2 = (2m_p)^2$ too, resulting in $(2m_p)^2 = (4m_p)^2$ which is obviously wrong?

Comment: Socratic rhetorical questions: You squared the l.h.side. What possessed you to then equate it to $m^2$?? You might drop that. Now the relativistic invariant it represents is true in all frames including the center of mass. This must also hold for the right-hand-side. What is *that* then at c.m. minimum possible momentum ("threshold")?

Comment: Oh right, the momentums on the right side are all zero for minimum energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the minimum energy needed for the reaction the products are assumed to be stationary, i.e. the momentums are zero. With $ \pmb p^2 = E^2 - \vec p^2 = E^2 = m^2$ follows:

$$({p_1^\mu}' + {p_2^\mu}' + {p_3^\mu}' + {\bar p_4^\mu}')^2 = (E_1 + E_2 + E_3 + E_4)^2 - (\vec p_1 + \vec p_2 + \vec p_3 + \vec p_4)^2 = (E_1 + E_2 + E_3 + E_4)^2 = (m_p + m_p + m_p + m_p)^2 = (4 m_p)^2$$